# How do I write data to csv file in different columns in python?

Tags: python, csv, multiple-columns

I have this type of data: 
`187500.0,-123736.88802,-122838.884334,-129570.670971,-129626.371518,-129585.154901,-129687.637649,-129628.182009`
received from a socket, and I'm trying to write every float in a different column.

What I do is this:

```
with open('output.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
                filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile,dialect = 'alphawaves',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                buffer = s.recv(1024)
                filewriter.writerow([buffer])
```

and the ouput on the csv file is this:
[output.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u07Ml.png)
What I want is have something like

```
     A           B          C                 D           E
1 187500.0 -123736.88802 -122838.884334 -129570.670971 -129626.371518
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to open the resulting csv file in a spreadsheet program and ending up with all of them in the same column.  This is not a problem with your csv output.  From what you have here, you are doing it right, and the data shows up right in the spreadsheet (just all in the same column).  This seems more like a problem with your spreadsheet program opening the csv file.  Are you sure you are selecting the right options when you open it in that spreadsheet program?  You have to make sure it knows this is comma delimited data.

Comment: I'm opening it with Excel, and it say in his description "file with values separated from comma " but I think it is a problem of language because in the Italian version for delimit data is used the ";" . But thank you @AgapwIesu! now I know that the problem is the spreadsheet program and not my code. I resolved using this guide [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-Convert-Text-to-Columns-Wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7)